# How to REPLACE a string in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table set up with the following rows:

```
Id_Customers               | Name
------------------------------------------------------- 
KG001TEI5                  | Dave Sullivan 
RU024GHE4                  | Rose Red White 
MK842LGS9                  | AKBLC DHEIFL
```

I want to `REPLACE` Name value with the following rule:

Replace `ABC` with `DEF` and `DEF` with `ABC`

Example: Original Name `AKBLC DHEIFL` after replacing `DKELF AHBICL`

This is how I approach it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[replace_name](@inputString VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @increment INT= 1;
         DECLARE @tmpString VARCHAR(1);
         WHILE @increment <= DATALENGTH(@inputString)
             BEGIN
                 SET @tmpString = (SUBSTRING(@inputString, @increment, 1));
                 IF(@tmpString LIKE '%[ABCDEF]%')
                     BEGIN
                         IF(@tmpString ='A')
                            SET @inputString = STUFF(@inputString, @increment, 1, 'D');
                         ELSE IF(@tmpString ='B')
                            SET @inputString = STUFF(@inputString, @increment, 1, 'E');
                         ELSE IF(@tmpString ='C')
                            SET @inputString = STUFF(@inputString, @increment, 1, 'F');
                         ELSE IF(@tmpString ='D')
                            SET @inputString = STUFF(@inputString, @increment, 1, 'A');
                         ELSE IF(@tmpString ='E')
                            SET @inputString = STUFF(@inputString, @increment, 1, 'B');
                         ELSE IF(@tmpString ='F')
                            SET @inputString = STUFF(@inputString, @increment, 1, 'C');
                    END;
                 SET @increment = @increment + 1;
             END;
         RETURN @inputString;
     END;
GO
```

Is there a better way to create it?

I'm not sure if this is good with million rows.

How to create a query to fill the requirements?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried... if you're unfamiliar SQL Server has a `replace` function.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. Do you need to replace string "ABC" with "DEF" or do you actually need to change the order of words around?

Comment: I just want to replace a string `A`, `B`, `C` with `D`, `E`, `F` and otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2017+, you may use `TRANSLATE()`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Id_Customers varchar(9),
   Name varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO Data (Id_Customers, Name)
VALUES
   ('KG001TEI5', 'Dave Sullivan'),
   ('RU024GHE4', 'Rose Red White'), 
   ('MK842LGS9', 'AKBLC DHEIFL')
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE Data
SET Name = TRANSLATE(Name, 'ABCDEF', 'DEFABC')
```

Result:

```
Id_Customers    Name
KG001TEI5       ADvB SullivDn
RU024GHE4       RosB RBA WhitB
MK842LGS9       DKELF AHBICL
```

For earlier versions, you need to use nested `REPLACE`s. Choose a character, which is not present in your data (`?` in the example):

```
UPDATE Data
SET Name = REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(
                             REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                   REPLACE(Name, 'F', '?'), 
                                'C', 'F'), 
                             '?', 'C'), 
                          'E', '?'), 
                       'B', 'E'), 
                    '?', 'B'), 
                 'A', '?'), 
              'D', 'A'), 
           '?', 'D')
```

Answer (score 1):

This query may work for you.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Test]
SET [Name] = 
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE([Name], 'A', '#')
                            , 'B', '$'),                                
                        'C', '^'),
                    'D', 'A'),
                'E', 'B'),
            'F', 'C'),
        '#', 'D'),
    '$', 'E'),
'^', 'F')
```

Comment: I believe this will result in original ABC letters i.e. it will replace them twice (A->D and then D->A)

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from this below script with 2 step REPLACE applied-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66bc7bd6dcfb266b2b3b3b3b1f7015c1)

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @T_new VARCHAR(100)

SET @T = 'AKBLC DHEIFL'

SELECT @T_new = REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE( REPLACE (@T,'A','##1'),
                'B','##2'), 'C','##3'), 'D','##4'), 'E','##5'), 'F','##6')

--##N used so that it not conflict with any existing value in general. 


SELECT REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE( REPLACE (@T_new,'##1','D'),
                '##2','E'), '##3','F'), '##4','A'), '##5','B'), '##6','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert them into separate special characters (which should not present in the Name column) and then replace them back accordingly.

try the following:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@str, 'A', '>'), 'B', '~'), 'C', '!'), 'D', '#'), 'E', '$'), 'F', '<'), '>', 'D'), '~', 'E'), '!', 'F'), '#', 'A'), '$', 'B'), '<', 'C')
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=01077b7bf5142746f76a6681d0e6a71b)**.